# Finding max value with tidyverse

Tags: r, max, tidyverse

I'm new to tidyverse and trying to learn it.

I want to find the max value of a column in a matrix. How I would do it with base R:

```
state.name[which.max(state.x77[,"Illiteracy"])]
```

Here is what I've tried using tidyverse so far:

```
state.x77 %>% state.name %>% which.max(.,"Illiteracy")


state.x77 %>% select(.,max(state.name))  


state.x77 %>%
group_by(state.name) %>%
summarize(max(.,))
```

I'm really unsure how to fit the Illiteracy part into, as well.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: `state.name[which.max(state.x77[,"Illiteracy"])]` should produce "Louisiana". This is from state.x77, which comes with R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first issue is that `state.x77` is a matrix. The tidyverse works on data frames. So you need to convert.

The tidyverse dislikes variables as row names - better to have their own column. There's a function for that: `tibble::rownames_to_column`.

`filter` selects rows according to the criteria you specify, so one way to get maximum Illiteracy is:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

state.x77 %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "Name") %>% 
  filter(Illiteracy == max(Illiteracy))

       Name Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad Frost  Area
1 Louisiana       3806   3545        2.8    68.76   13.2    42.2    12 44930
```

You can add `%>% select(Name)` or `%>% pull(Name)` to the end if all you want is the state name.

Comment: Could this also be done using slice function in tidyverse ?